# Java Jpa @GeneratedValue smart generation for both null and non-null values

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, identity

I have 10-15 entities in my local postgres database.
All entities contains one identity of type Integer. See the code fragment down below.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
@NonNull
private Integer id;
```

My CRUD  (T is my entity) class contains create method for inserting new entities into appropriate table

```
private final JpaRepository<T, Integer> jpaRepository;
private final EntityManager entityManager;
private final Class<T> clazz;

@Override
public T create(T entity) {
    return getJpaRepository().saveAndFlush(entity);
}
```

I am trying to achieve next goals:

1. If I call create method where entity contains some value (`!= null`) for id field then save it exactly with that id (not generated).
2. If I call create method where entity contains value `== null` - then create it with auto-generated id as database provide.

Why i need this?
I'm trying to fill in-memory small database with entities that I grab from JSON entity and save it with same id's.

My problem is that annotation `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO/SEQUENCE/TABLE/IDENTITY)` not gives me such things.
If I remove `GeneratedValue` annotation then `null` values will not be handled properly.

I will highly appreciate your suggestions.

Add CommentCollapse

Comment: The JPA spec doesn't support selective generation of values when null only. You have to go to specific JPA providers extensions to look for that support. I know that DataNucleus JPA allows that, but you don't say which JPA provider you're using so no further comment is possible

Comment: @BillyFrost provider is Hibernate

Comment: and when you look in its documentation about trying to do what you want?

Comment: @BillyFrost, something like EntityManager.persist(entity) and flush persistence context, but it cause problems with constraints (detached entities) unlike jpaRepository.saveAndFlush(entity).

Comment: which has got what to do with value generation? that your question is about, and I suggested you look in the Hibernate docs about

Answer (score -1):

Spring Data is no magic and if you look at the implementation of the `saveAndFlush` method, or rather at the [implementation of `save`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/ccf6039be5243de892598cc472039fbf53b6b67b/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L592) which it calls,
you'll see that it checks `if (entityInformation.isNew(entity))`.
How does it check `isNew`? Simply by checking whether the ID is NULL.

But you can simply use the entity manager directly! `merge` will do what you want. It's there to bring detached entities back into the managed state and copy its changes to the peristed entity. But if no persisted entity exists, it will simply create it.

Not that you *do not* want to always use `merge` instead of `persist`, this comes at a cost. See [How do persist and merge work in JPA](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-persist-and-merge/)

Comment: This is not correct. The id is also generated in this case when using merge.